Quarto will not render autoplot on library(AER) "UKNonDurables" data set
I am trying to autoplot the UKNonDurables data that is in the AER package in a Quarto Document. When I run the code in the Chunk it works fine however, when I render to HTML I get the following message.
processing file: Untitled.qmd
 |...................................                 |  67% [unnamed-chunk-1]
Quitting from lines 8-11 [unnamed-chunk-1] (Untitled.qmd)
Error:
! object 'UKNonDurables' not found
Backtrace:
1. ggplot2::autoplot(UKNonDurables)
                                                                                                           
Execution halted

Here is the code:
library(AER)
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(UKNonDurables)

I have also written the code as follows:
library(AER)
data("UKNonDurables")
autoplot(UKNonDurables)

I get error message:
processing file: Untitled.qmd
  |...................................                 |  67% [unnamed-chunk-1]
Quitting from lines 8-11 [unnamed-chunk-1] (Untitled.qmd)
Error in `autoplot()`:
! could not find function "autoplot"
                                                                                                            
Execution halted

